# Convert this function from VB to c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I've been banging my head against the wall trying to convert this classic asp (vb) to asp.net c# with no luck.

```
Function Decrypt1(s)
    if isnull(s) then
    Decrypt1 = ""
    else
    Dim r, i, ch
    For i = 1 To Len(s)/2
        ch = "&H" & Mid(s, (i-1)*2+1, 2)
        ch = ch Xor 111
        r = r & Chr(ch)
    Next
    Decrypt1 = strReverse(r)
    end if
End Function
```

any takers?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT - "0B031D00180003030A07" should decrypt to "helloworld"

Comment: Have you tried an online converter?

Comment: whats the datatype of s?

Comment: Pretty lame crypto

Comment: show us what you have so far, we might be able to sort it out.

Comment: Break the function down into parts. Google how to do each specific part in C#. How to test for null, how to test the length of a string, how to loop, how to get a substring, etc. Put those parts back together.

Comment: @dlatikay   ---   the comments are restricting me from posting my code :(

Comment: @AnthonyPegram - thats exactly what Ive been doing ... getting hung up on the XOR equivelant

Comment: just curious ... am new posting questions to stackoverflow .. but why do i have -3 on my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

Here's your c-sharp method for decrypting your string:

```
    public static string Decrypt1(string s)
    {
        string functionReturnValue = null;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        {
            functionReturnValue = "";
        }
        else
        {
            string r = null;
            int ch = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length / 2; i++)
            {
                ch = int.Parse(s.Substring((i) * 2, 2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
                ch = ch ^ 111;
                r = r + (char)(ch);
            }

            var charArray = r.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(charArray);
            functionReturnValue = new string(charArray);
        }
        return functionReturnValue;
    }
```

[Try it on Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EO1XJ9)

Comment: &H is 0x in c#, the hex designator. probably no converter is smart enough to figure this out.

Comment: yeah the above code looks just like the code I got from the converter

Comment: there is so much weird implicit casting going on that this is not as trivial as it seems at first glance. the xor is fine though; the ^ operator

Comment: Well, I practically wrote it by hand.. Can you show what type of string/data the function would expect? It looks like something in Hex format.

Comment: that &h is really meant to be numeric. vb would have boxed it and xor'ed as an int, as incredible this may seem to a sane c# dev

Comment: @vendettamit - 0B031D00180003030A07 should decrypt to helloworld

Comment: @MikeMorehead Now we're going somewhere.. Update your question with this information.

Comment: same error that I got

Operator '^' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'

Comment: I just removed the unwanted line before reversing the array. See updated answer.

Comment: @MikeMorehead Try this version. I've this working on my tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can try online converters.

Here is one of those: http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 0):

This one works with your helloworld example:

```
    public static string Decrypt1(string s)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            return string.Empty;

        string r = null;
        for (int i = 1; i <= s.Length / 2; i++)
        {
            var ch = Convert.ToUInt32(s.Substring((i - 1) * 2, 2), 16);
            ch = ch ^ 111;
            r = r + (char)(ch);
        }

        var charArray = r.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(charArray);

        return new string(charArray);
    }
```

Comment: @MikeMorehead No worries. Feel free to mark the answer as useful. :-)